# how to avoid double borders in HTML graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot, pygraphviz

I have the following simple
Node in a graph:

```
    digraph "graph.svg" {
    graph [bgcolor="#333333" fontcolor=white fontname=Helvetica fontsize=16 label="Title" rankdir=TB]
        0 [label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="2" BGCOLOR="#006699"> 
                      <TR>
                        <TD COLSPAN="2">Node Titel</TD>
                      </TR>
                      <TR>
                        <TD COLSPAN="2">Sieve</TD>
                      </TR>
                      <TR>
                        <TD CELLPADDING="0">
                            <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" BGCOLOR="#006699"> 
                              <TR>
                                <TD BORDER="1">in 1</TD>
                              </TR>
                              <TR>
                                <TD BORDER="1">in 2</TD>
                              </TR> 
                           </TABLE>
                        </TD>
                        <TD CELLPADDING="0">
                             <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" BGCOLOR="#006699"> 
                              <TR>
                                <TD BORDER="1">out 1</TD>
                              </TR>
                              <TR>
                                <TD BORDER="1">out 2</TD>
                              </TR> 
                              <TR>
                                <TD BORDER="1">out 3</TD>
                              </TR> 
                           </TABLE>
                        </TD>
                        </TR> 
                   </TABLE>> shape=plaintext]
}
```

Which produces this output:

[image: Output]

How can I make the borders align such that no double borders appear anywhere between the nested tables?
I managed to fiddle around with the CELLSPADING=-1
but I don't think that is the way to go?
I cannot use the COLSPAN option because the inputs and outputs ports are variable in size, that's why I solved this with a nested table for both input and output cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you were near there

```
digraph "graph.svg" {
graph [bgcolor="#333333" fontcolor=white fontname=Helvetica fontsize=16 label="Title" rankdir=TB]
    0 [label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="2" BGCOLOR="#006699"> 
                  <TR>
                    <TD COLSPAN="2">Node Titel</TD>
                  </TR>
                  <TR>
                    <TD COLSPAN="2">Sieve</TD>
                  </TR>
                  <TR>
                    <TD CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0">
                        <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" BGCOLOR="#006699"> 
                          <TR>
                            <TD BORDER="1">in 1</TD>
                          </TR>
                          <TR>
                            <TD BORDER="1">in 2</TD>
                          </TR> 
                       </TABLE>
                    </TD>
                    <TD CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0">
                         <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" BGCOLOR="#006699"> 
                          <TR>
                            <TD BORDER="1">out 1</TD>
                          </TR>
                          <TR>
                            <TD BORDER="1">out 2</TD>
                          </TR> 
                          <TR>
                            <TD BORDER="1">out 3</TD>
                          </TR> 
                       </TABLE>
                    </TD>
                    </TR> 
               </TABLE>> shape=plaintext]
}
```

[image]